# SQLiteConstraintException: How to map "no relationship" with a FOREIGN KEY in Room

Tags: java, android, orm, foreign-keys, android-room

I am using the Android Room Persistence Library as ORM.

I have the following Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "log_entries",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Serving.class,
                        parentColumns = "id",
                        childColumns = "foodId",
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
public class LogEntry {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    private long servingId;

    // ...
}
```

There are some log entries which have a serving and some which don't. Adding a log entry
which has a serving works fine, but adding one with id = 0 to represent 'no relation' causes a
`SQLiteConstraintException` with the message

> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

```
// ...
LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
logEntry.setServingId(0);
// ...

db.logEntryDao().add(logEntry);
```

So, how can I express the fact that a log entry has no serving in Room?

Comment: I posted this question, after I already found the solution by myself. I hope it will be helpful for other people as well, that is why I asked it in such a style. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Long` as datatype and insert the entity with `null` as `servingId`.

```
// ...
LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
logEntry.setServingId(null);
// ...

db.logEntryDao().add(logEntry);
```