# Update failing on Self Referential Foreign key with Room update method

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-room

I need to create folder structure using **Room**. I had followed this approach.

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = NodeEntity.class,
        parentColumns = "id",
        childColumns = "parentId", onDelete = CASCADE), indices = {@Index(value = {"parentId"})})
public class NodeEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String id;
    private int isLeafItem;
    private int level;
    private String name;
    private String parentId;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private String tags;
    @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

My Node DAO is like this.

```
@Dao
public interface NodeDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void createNode(NodeEntity nodeEntity);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM NodeEntity WHERE parentId = :parentId ")
    Flowable<List<NodeEntity>> getNodesByParentId(String parentId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM NodeEntity WHERE level = :level")
    Flowable<List<NodeEntity>> getNodesByLevel(int level);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM NodeEntity WHERE id = :nodeId")
    Single<NodeEntity> getNode(String nodeId);

    @Update(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void updateNode(NodeEntity node);

    @Delete
    void deleteNode(NodeEntity nodeEntity);
}
```

All operations are working fine. but if I tried to move one folder to another folder, that means you need to change the parentId of the folder you are moving. When I do that, the update is failing without any exception.

so I ended up writing a separate method like this.

```
@Query("UPDATE NodeEntity SET parentId = :newParentId, level=:newLevelId where id=:id AND parentId=:parentId")
    void moveNode(String newParentId,int newLevelId, String id, String parentId);
```

Above move, method is working as expected. But not sure, why @update is silently failing.

Comment: Please explain in detail what "the update is failing" means.

Comment: If you call updateNode(NodeEntity node); method, nothing is happening !! . If you query Node table after that,  you won't see any changes. I can push my code to repo, if you need more clarity on this @CommonsWare.. Thanks ...

Comment: I would recommend creating a complete sample project that reproduces the problem, then [filing an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448). What you describe feels like a bug.

Comment: The second WHERE condition in your solution is redundant. "id" already is unique.