# Room error - how to deal with?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I use Android Room library. I have entity Products:

```
@Entity(tableName = "products", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
        entity = Category.class,
        parentColumns = "code",
        childColumns = "category_id"))
public class Product {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    private String categoryId;
```

and second entity.

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
public class Category {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String code;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Ignore
    private List<Product> products;
```

When I try insert list of products:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                MyApplication.get().getDB().productDao().insertAll(productList);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
```

I get error when try insert products to DB.

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633483/android-room-foreign-key-constraint-failed

Comment: @kamal verma in which place is a duplicate? I do not want to use my String UUID or some other kind of crutch

Comment: same error  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633483/android-room-foreign-key-constraint-failed

Comment: In this question, he used int instead of Integer. At me Long. The error is the same, but the code is different, and the problem is different. Read the question carefully

Comment: please add your dao class code here

Answer (score 1):

I think this might have to do with the `@Ignore` annotation in the `Category` class, where you define the one-to-many owning relationship to `Product`.

Try and see what happens when you remove the `@Ignore` annotation. If that does not work, you can also use the `@Relation` annotation to define a one-to-many relationship. (Source: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330452/android-persistence-room-cannot-figure-out-how-to-read-this-field-from-a-curso/44424148#44424148))